# How to get a wrapper <div> to fill 100% of a browser's height regardless of the height of the enclosed content?

Tags: css, html, height

This question seems to have been answered a gazillion times in various forms but I still can't find an answer that works for me. Put simply, I have this layout:

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="header"></div>
        <div class="body"></div>
        <div class="footer"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I want `wrapper` to be centered horizontally in the browser and for it to fill 100% of the browser's height. Each of the enclosed `<div>` elements has a fixed height that more often than not sum to a height that is greater than the browser window's height. If this is the case, I get the layout I want.

If, however, the browser window's height is greater than the combined height of the enclosed `<div>` elements (as is the case on an iMac or portrait iPhone orientation, for example), then the `wrapper` seems to stop with the end of the `footer` and the rest of the window below this is `<body>` background. The `wrapper` background and `<body>` background are different colours, so it is quite obvious that this is the case.

Does anyone have a CSS solution to this, so that the `wrapper` fills the browser height regardless of whether this height is greater or less than the combined height of the content?

**EDIT: ANSWER:**

The answer was a combination of the answers below and something that I happened upon just now: In the CSS, do this:

```
body, html {
    height:  100%;
    margin:  0px auto;
    padding: 0px auto;
}

.wrapper {
    height:     auto;       /* These two lines were the key. */
    min-height: 100%
    /*overflow:   hidden;*/ /* Do not use this, it crops in small browsers. */
    margin:     0px auto;
    padding:    0px auto;
 }
```

Comment: Does the [first SO-suggested question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1575141/11683) not help you?

Comment: can you create some jsfiddle for us?

Comment: Nice job, internet friend. Your two "key lines" solved my issue!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to set a div height to 100%, you should set the height of html and body to 100% as well. Then you can add 100% to the div.

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
border: 1px solid red;
height: 100%;
margin: 0px auto;
overflow: hidden;
}

body, html {
height: 100%;
}
```

Take a look at this [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mt5wL/1/).

Comment: Thanks. All the answers have been along the same lines, but it seemed the key was the `overflow: hidden` part. I now have the layout I want in each type of orientation.

Comment: Actually, this is still not right - the `overflow:hidden` chops the content in landscape iPhone orientation. Any thoughts?

Comment: Adding overflow-x: auto will add a vertical scrollbar when your divs are bigger than your wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have an element that fills 100% the height of the viewport, you need to have:

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for centering wraper div

```
body{
   margin:0px;
   padding:0px;
  height:100%;
}
.wraper{
   width:90%;
   margin:0px auto;
  height:100%;
  overflow:hidden
}
```